# it always gives false ,i used this hasGroup function in other apps in all the apps this function returns false

Tags: python, django, filter, model, django-users

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
def hasGroup(user,groupName):
    group = Group.objects.filter(name=groupName)
    return True if group in user.groups.all() else False
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
def hasGroup(user, groupName):
    return user.groups.filter(name=groupName).exists()
```

will save you a query, and will work as you expected.